# Selecting items from two arrays without duplicate indices to get maximum sum

Tags: dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms

Given two arrays both of length n, you have to choose exactly *k* values from the array 1 and *n-k* values from the other array, such that the sum of these values is maximum, with constraint that if you choose a value from some index of any of the array you cannot choose from same index of second array.

I have encountered this type of question in many places but never able to solve it, and I always have an Intuition that this is a dynamic programming problem but never able to prove it. I do not quite understand If there exist a dynamic solution or not?

Comment: @Evil Edited it, seems its was greedy problem before, now changed?

Comment: Do you mean "given two arrays both of length n and a number $k$, you have to choose exactly k values from the array 1 and n-k values from the other array, such that the sum of these values is maximum."?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Yes but our array cannot use two values which came from same index

Comment: @Apass.Jack I've found a dp solution which works in O(n*k), thought you would want to know, its 2-D dp ,we need to create dp[n][k], lets define dp[i][j] as the maximum value one can obtain if we choose exactly k values from array1 up until now, for calculation part dp[i][j]=max(arr2[i] + dp[i-1][j], arr2[i]+dp[i-1][j-1]), that is max(current value is part of solution, its not part of solution). should I post it as a solution? not sure if I committed any mistake, I only tried it on two test cases not too big, not sure if my solution is entirely correct.

Comment: "lets define dp[i][j] as the maximum value one can obtain if we choose exactly k values", you meant exactly "i values". It is up to you to post the dp approach or not. Although the dp approach is slower in the case of 2 arrays, it can be generalized to 3 or more arrays easily

Comment: @Apass.Jack Uploaded my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to interpret the problem.

**$k$ is part of the input**

Let $a=(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$ and $b=(b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n)$ be the two given array. Suppose we have chosen $k$ values from array $a$, $a_i$ where $i$ ranges over some index set $I$ that has $k$ elements. Then we have to choose the $n-k$ values from array $b$, $b_j$ where $j$ ranges over all indices that are not in $I$. The sum of all numbers are

$$\sum_{i\in I}a_i+\sum_{i\not\in I}b_i=(\sum_{i\in I}a_i-\sum_{i\in I}b_i) + (\sum_{i\in I}b_i+\sum_{i\not\in I}b_i)=\sum_{i\in I}(a_i-b_i)+\sum_ib_i$$

Since $\sum_ib_i$ is a constant, the sum reaches the maximum if $\sum_{i\in I}(a_i-b_i)$ reaches the maximum. So we can select the $k$ largest elements in the array $a-b=(a_1-b_1, a_2-b_2, \cdots, a_n-b_n)$. The indices of the those elements are the indices of the elements in $a$ that we should choose.

The $k$ largest element can be selected in $O(n)$ time using [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect), this algorithm can be implemented in $O(n)$ time. It can also be implemented in $O(n\log n)$ easily by sorting the array $a-b.$

**$k$ is not part of the input**

Solve the previous problem  for $k=0$. Let the maximum sum obtained by $m_0$.
Solve the previous problem again but for $k=1$. Let the maximum sum obtained by $m_1$.
And so on.

Find the maximum number among $m_0, m_1, \cdots, m_n$. That is the maximum sum we want in this interpretation the problem. A bit of extra bookkeeping will let us know the numbers we should select to reach that maximum sum.

**Exercises**

**Exercise 1.** How about the case of smallest sum?

**Exercise 2.** How about exactly $k-1$ values from the first array and $n-k$ values from the other array?

Comment: I didn't understand RHS of the equation, can you help me with that? I mean why does that work? in the array a-b many values will go negative.

Comment: Check this example,  $(a_1+a_3)+(b_2+b_4)=((a_1-b_1)+(a_3-b_3))+(b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4)$

Comment: I got it Thanks, very elegant solution requiring mathematics, So this is Greedy problem Requiring sorting(NLogn), not a Dynammic problem? Am I correct?

Comment: You are. The approach is certainly not dynamic programming. The algorithm could be called a greedy algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Answering My own Question: though time complexity of the greedy solution is much better.

Dynamic Programming Approach:

We Have: $array1$ and $array2$ both of length $n$ and we are required to choose exactly $k$ values from $array1$ and $n-k$ values from $array2$

Now we iterate through each value pairs from both the array and fill the array-dp row by row as we iterate through each column.

Create 2-Array dp[n][k], 
Where,

$ n$ - $length$ $of$ $each$ $array$

$ k$ - $no$ $of$ $values$ $to$ $be$ $taken$ $from$ $array1$

**Definition:** $dp[i][j]$ - is the maximum value one can obtain if we are done iterating through $i$ value pairs and exactly $j$ values are taken from $array1$

**Formula:** $dp[i][j]$ $=$ $max(array2[i]+dp[i-1][j],array1[i]+dp[i-1][j-1])$

**Explanation of Formula:** for each $(i,j)$ in the table we choose the maximum between two values that are,

1. if we choose a value from $array2$ that means we now need to choose exactly $j$ values from previous $i-1$ value pairs.(remember we needed to choose exactly $k$ values from $array1$)
2. if we choose a value from $array1$ that means we now have to choose exactly $j-1$ values from previous $i-1$ value pairs.

To get the maximum value obtainable we look for value of **dp[n][k]**

**Time complexity:** $O(n*k)$

Comment: This answer looks good.

Comment: How to initiate dp array

Answer (score 0):

Given two arrays A and B, for each index i your sum includes either A[i] or B[i]. You can start adding all B[i], then picking k indexes i and replacing B[i] with A[i], increasing the sum by (A[i] - B[i]).

You make the sum largest by calculating all values A[i] - B[i] and storing them into an array C, selecting the k largest values in C, and adding them to the sum.

Finding the k-largest element of an array can be done in O(n), and adding the k largest elements can again be done in linear time (add all elements that are greater than the k-largest element and count them at the same time. If you found k' elements greater than the k-largest, then there are at least k-k' elements equal to the k-largest.

Pseudocode: Let S be the sum of B[i] for 1 ≤ b ≤ n. Let C[i] = A[i] - B[i] for 1 ≤ i ≤ n. Find the k largest element of C, and let its value be K. Add all elements C[i] to S where 1 ≤ i ≤ n and C[i] > k. Let k' be the number of elements C[i] for 1 ≤ i ≤ n with C[i] > k. Increase S by (k - k') * K.